# PHP, MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE {$_FILES[file][name]} as a variable filename

Tags: php, mysql, variables, load, file-io

I am creating a function that imports a file and creates a table and names it $memberID_$filename

It chokes when it tries to convert the filename over. I am thinking it is because of the .txt but not really sure.

Line 23 is the issue.

```
<?php
var_dump($_FILES);
//db connection
require 'dbConnect.php';
//session file
require_once('../auth.php');
function uploadList(){
        //var_dump($_FILES);
        if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain")
                {
                if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
                        {
                        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
                }
                else
                        {
                        dbConnect();
                        mysql_select_db('mailList') or die(mysql_error());
                        //$file=''
                        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                        $presql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (`$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]_$file`)";
                        $sql = <<<EOF
                        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE {$_FILES[file][name]}
                        INTO TABLE (`$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]_$file`)
                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\\'
                        LINES TERMINATED BY "\\r\\n"
                        IGNORE 1 LINES
EOF;
                        mysql_query($presql);
                        mysql_query($sql);
                        var_dump($sql);
                        if(mysql_error())
                                {
                                echo(mysql_error());
                        }
                        else
                                {
                                print('Import of campaign emails sucessfull into mysql table.');
                        }
                }
        }
        else
                {
                print('Invalid file type. Please make sure it is a text file.');
        }
}

//var_dump($_FILES);
uploadList();
?>
```

**************************error*************************
array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(14) "emailsTest.txt" ["type"]=> string(10) "text/plain" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpW7Cu2I" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(61) } } 
Notice: Use of undefined constant file - assumed 'file' in /home/nyctelecomm.com/www/mail/import.php on line 23

Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' in /home/nyctelecomm.com/www/mail/import.php on line 23
string(178) "   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE emailsTest.txt INTO TABLE (`3_emailsTest.txt`) FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n" IGNORE 1 LINES" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'emailsTest.txt INTO TABLE (`3_emailsTest.txt`) FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OP' at line 1

Comment: I have tried '{$_FILES[file][name]}'   '{$_FILES[file]['name']}'  '{$_FILES['file']['name']}' {$_FILES[file][name]}  {$_FILES['file']['name']}  $_FILES[file][name]    $_FILES[file]['name']   $_FILES['file']['name']    '$_FILES[file][name]' and  '$_FILES['file']['name']'